# Automate import of list from salesforce to mailchimp

Tags: drupal-7, salesforce, integration, mailchimp

I have to work on this task..but I have no idea how to start. I googled it..but did not get the relevant answer.
I have various forms on website. These forms are made using drupal. On the submission of form I have to push the contents in the contacts and activities of salesforce. For eg let's say ABC has downloaded a newsletter. Then ABC will go in contact(of salesforce) and newsletter will go in activity(of salesforce) of ABC in salesforce. Now using the activity I have to create a custom list and import it to mail chimp.
My research :
Drupal to salesforce :
It says drupal has salesforce suite module where you can map drupal entities with salesforce field. And on submission it will automatically go to salesforce.
Salesforce to mailchimp:
Am not sure of this part. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks .

Comment: Please ask if any clarification is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Zapier](https://zapier.com/) for this. I believe this [zap](https://zapier.com/zapbook/zaps/2170/add-new-salesforce-contacts-to-mailchimp-as-subscribers-on-a-list/) will do what you want.

If you want to customize the integration you can see a full list of triggers and actions for both mailchimp and salesforce [here](https://zapier.com/zapbook/mailchimp/salesforce/)

Essentially, you can connect any of those triggers on the left to any of the actions on the right. This way you can make your own custom integrations to do whatever you need. You should be able to satisfy this requirement with this.